# Applying the distributed alignment to the context on Figs

Tags: captions, alignment, justification

How to apply the distributed alignment to the context on Figure?

I tried to apply `\justifying`, or `caption` package and `\captionsetup` function.

However, they break the journal caption template.

```
\begin{figure*}[pt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=17.5cm, clip, keepaspectratio]{Latex_format_IEEE_access/figures/figure_system_arhchitecture.pdf}
    \caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
    \label{fig:system_architecture}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your image that we can test it as it is. Due to used unnatural caption text yaou can expect strang caption formatting. Please mimic caption text with some more natural caption text. For example with `\lipsum[66]` (defined by `lipsum` package.

Answer (score 1):

- this is quite old question with lack of needed information as is used `documentclass`,
- you have problem with formatting caption text because there you put some non natural text, which is hard formatting,
- it is not clear, what you mean with `distributed alignment to the context on Figure`,

I guess, that you probably use `ieeeaccess` documentclass. If I'm right, than is not good idea to change default caption settings, eventually mimic caption for `figure*` , which `ieeeaccess` not natively support. For example:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={sf,scriptsize},
            labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}]
            {caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\Figure[ht]{example-image-duck}
           {Test figure \label{fig:test}}

\begin{figure*}[pt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{\lipsum[66]}
    \label{fig:system_architecture}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\EOD
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that? (immediately after `\begin{figure}`)

```
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}% raggedright, raggedleft, centering
```

It needs the `caption` package.